# Puppeteer on an express.js server cookies

Tags: express, puppeteer

I'm running puppeteer on an express.js server. Some of the webpages I go to require puppeteer to login.  I'm using

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    userDataDir: "./user_data/",
  });
```

to store the session cookies so that I don't have to login each time, however, whenever I restart the express.js server the cookies seem to disappear and I'm required to login again.

Why does this keep happening? And is there a way to stop it from happening?

Comment: Looks like this was once a Chromium bug. What version of puppeteer are you using? https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/921

Also it's possible that puppeteer won't resolve `./` correctly, would try the same with an absolute filepath

Comment: I've tried the absolute file path and that didn't work. Chromium `Version 79.0.3945.0 (Developer Build) (64-bit)`.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I can't say I know exactly what's causing your issue, but I also experienced a number of difficulties getting puppeteer to properly save all session data (building bots to login to bank accounts to check balances, etc.) To remedy this I created some helper functions that use zlib to pack up the cookies (both from the direct Chrome Dev Tools client command, and the puppeteer API) along with the entire user data directory as a base64 string.

Here's a [gist](https://gist.github.com/nicoandmee/84e7a5dd3e144cf96bb6fdfc9287d7ba) I created that you can run. You will need to decide where to store the base64 string containing the session data, but once done, you can import it into any puppeteer instance using the appropriate function and replicate the exact browser state. In my case, I am using firestore but obviously any storage solution will do.